# PHP shell_exec() Command not found

Tags: php, http, command-not-found

I need to execute a program using php, the file in question is ClustalW (clustalw2). My apache user is http using fish shell, so I moved clustalw2 to `/srv/http/Clustal` and added the dir to fish path. 
If I log in into http using terminal and run `clustalw2 -INFILE=input_file -OUTFILE=output_file` everything works as expected. 
But every time I run `shell_exec('clustalw2 -INFILE=input_file -OUTFILE=output_file');` nothing happens and I get this error log: `sh: line 1: clustalw2: command not found`

---

**If I run:**

```
<?php
echo "USER: ".shell_exec('whoami')."<br>";
echo "SHELL: ".shell_exec('echo "$SHELL"')."<br>";
echo "WHICH clustalw2: ".shell_exec('which clustalw2');
```

**Output:**
USER: http
SHELL: /usr/bin/fish
WHICH clustalw2:

---

If I run `which clustalw2` in terminal using http user:

```
/srv/http/Clustalw/clustalw2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program can't find `clustalw2` because `clustalw2` isn't in the `$PATH`.

In your case, the easiest solution is to replace `clustalw2` with the full path, `/srv/http/Clustalw/clustalw2` as the first parameter to `shell_exec`.